# How do I make a button disappear after a certain amount of clicks

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button is it possible to make it disappear if I click it say 5 times? need to know for a little project I'm working on!
any response is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, this would be fairly trivial with some JavaScript. One approach would be to decrement a counter when the button is clicked and when it reaches zero disable/hide the button. A library such as jQuery could make the job easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `id` to your button.
`<Button id='myButton' onclick="myFunction()">`

On every click of button, keep incrementing the counter (I think you know how to do it)

After the counter is reached,
`document.getElementById("Your_button_id_here").style.visibility = "hidden";`

```
<script>
var counter=0;
function myFunction() {
    //increment counter
    counter+=1;
    if(counter>4)
        document.getElementById("Your_button_id_here").style.visibility = "hidden"
}
</script>
```

However, I think disabling would be more proper:
`document.getElementById("Your_button_id_here").disabled=true`

Comment: How do I get it to increase the counter per button click? Sorry still learning javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code

HTML:

```
<button type='button' id='button_test_clicks'>
  Click me!
</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function(){
  var counter=0; // counter clicks initialization
  var button=document.getElementById('button_test_clicks'); //Our button
  button.addEventListener("click",function(){ //add a click event to button
    counter++; //incement the counter
    console.log(a);
    if(counter==5){
      button.style.display = 'none'; //hide if the clicks reached to 5
    }
  });
})();
```

But whenever the page refresh happens counter sets to zero, to avoid refresh problems learn about `localStorage` in javascript.

Comment: `counter==5` would probably cause unexpected type coercion. This is javascript. The correct syntax would be `counter===5` or `counter >= 5`

Answer (score 0):

You could have a simple script like this :

```
    var nbClicks=0;
    function btnOnClick(btn){
      if(++nbClicks>5){btn.style.display='none';}
    }
```

And use it like that :
        <input type="button" onclick="btnOnClick(this)" value="Click me 6 times !">

Answer (score 0):

On every click just increment a variable's value and after got desired number, hide it by css and js.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small example with jQuery

```js
var count = 0;
$("#b1").click(function() {
  count++;
  if (count >= 5) {
    $("#b1").hide();
  }

});
```

```html
<html>
<header>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</header>

<body>
  <button id="b1">5 Clicks</button>
</body>

</html>
```